# How can I change a local variable assigned to the value of a global one without changing the global variable?

Tags: python, global-variables, python-2.x, local-variables

So this is basically how the code works that I'm using.

```
global Gvar
Gvar = ["Hello"]

def someFunction():
    Lvar = Gvar
    Lvar.append("World")
    print(Lvar)
    print(Gvar)

someFunction()
```

This outputs "Hello World" twice. How can I prevent the change of the global variable when I change the local?

Thanks in advance, I hope someone can help me out.

Comment: Make a copy of the list when assigning it to the local variable.

Comment: You may want to read up on how Python variables and assignment work: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: Wow quick reply. I think that will help me out. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is the following line:

```
Lvar = Gvar
```

Since `Gvar` is a list and therefore a complex datatype, Python won't copy the value but instead references to the variable. So whether you modify `Lvar` or `Gvar` won't make a difference at this point. Instead, you probably want to copy the values which you can achieve in different ways, e.g.:

```
Lvar = Gvar[:]
```

Alternatively, you can use the [copy module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html). Check out the [Python FAQs](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-copy-an-object-in-python) for more information on this.

---

For completion, this is how your modified code would look:

```
global Gvar
Gvar = ["Hello"]

def someFunction():
    Lvar = Gvar[:]
    Lvar.append("World")
    print(Lvar)
    print(Gvar)

someFunction()
```

As a side note, variable names in Python should be lower-case - upper-case is typically used for class definitions only.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `shallow copy` to do htis task :

```
global Gvar
Gvar = ["Hello"]

def someFunction():
    Lvar = Gvar.copy()

    Lvar.append("World")
    print(Lvar)
    print(Gvar)

someFunction()
```

Output :

```
['Hello', 'World']
['Hello']
```

You also use `deepcopy` to do this task :

```
import copy
global Gvar
Gvar = ["Hello"]

def someFunction():
    Lvar = copy.deepcopy(Gvar)
    Lvar.append("World")
    print(Lvar)
    print(Gvar)

someFunction()
```

Output :

```
['Hello', 'World']
['Hello']
```

**N.B :** if you use `Python 2.7.6` then use `print Lvar` instead of `print(Lvar)` and `print Gvar` instead of `print(Gvar)`.